# Conditionally getting json data using java

Tags: java, json

below is my code where Im trying to check id id =101 and getting the name= Pushkar assosiated with the id=101.But the code is not working as expected.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class A6 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, JSONException{

    String out1="{\"Employee\":[{\"id\":\"101\",\"name\":\"Pushkar\",\"salary\":\"5000\"},{\"id\":\"102\",\"name\":\"Rahul\",\"salary\":\"4000\"},{\"id\":\"103\",\"name\":\"tanveer\",\"salary\":\"56678\"}]}";

//System.out.println(out1);
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
JSONObject obj=(JSONObject)parser.parse(out1);
//System.out.print(obj);
JSONArray jarr=(JSONArray)obj.get("Employee");
//System.out.print(jarr);
for (int i=0;i<jarr.size();i++)
{ 


    JSONObject jobj=(JSONObject)jarr.get(i);
    String ID1=(String)jobj.get("id");
    System.out.println(ID1);
    if(ID1!=null && out1.equals(ID1))
    {
    System.out.println("NAME"+jobj.get("name"));
    }



}
}}
```

Comment: check your if condition     if(ID1!=null && out1.equals(ID1))  here out1 and ID1 might have different values hence your condition will not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you compare out1 with ID1? Either you want to check if out1 contains ID1 (which is not very meaningfull, as you retrieve ID1 from out1) or you want to verify that ID1 equals 101. In that case you would rather want to say something like:

```
if(ID1!=null && "101".equals(ID1))
    {
    System.out.println("NAME"+jobj.get("name"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change if condition like this:

```
if(ID1!=null && out1.contains(ID1))
    {
    System.out.println("NAME"+jobj.get("name"));
    }
```

Thanks.